# Case Insensitive comparison for collection against multiple options

Tags: nunit

I am trying to use NUnit to write an assertion that all the (string) members of a collection are one of a set of possibilities in a case insensitive manner. I thought I had figured it out, but it won't compile.

I thought this syntax would work:

```
Assert.That(new string[] { "red", "red", "red", "green" }, 
    Is.All.AnyOf(new string[] { "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN" }).IgnoreCase);
```

However this errors with

```
'Constraint' does not contain a definition for 'IgnoreCase' and no
extension method 'IgnoreCase' accepting a first argument of
type 'Constraint' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
assembly reference?)
```

The simpler test of a single item is one of a set of possibilities in a case insensitive manner works as expected.

```
Assert.That("red", Is.AnyOf(new string[] { "RED", "BLUE" }).IgnoreCase);
```

How should I phrase this assertion? Or is it a bug that this does not work?

Comment: Could you use `CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf`? Just convert all `ToLower()`...`CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(new string[] { "RED", "GREEN" }.Select(s => s.ToLower()), new string[] { "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN" }.Select(s => s.ToLower()))`

Comment: @Johnny That works for my example, but not for my actual case because the first array is more like `new string [] { "RED", "RED", "RED", "GREEN" }`. The first array is much longer than the second and includes many repeated elements.

Comment: @Johnny I have updated the example in the question to include repeated elements.

Comment: But you could use `Distinct()`. That will remove duplicates...

Comment: Could something like this work for your case: `CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(new string[] { "RED", "RED", "RED", "GREEN" }.Select(s => s.ToLower()).Distinct(), new string[] { "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN" }.Select(s => s.ToLower()).Distinct())`?

Comment: @Johnny That would work, as does another workaround that I am using. But I'd rather use `.IgnoreCase` than `.ToLower()` and I really want to know why the seemingly idiomatic way does not work. Am I misunderstanding the idioms?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into the issue because of the order of precedence of the operations. You want the `.IgnoreCase` modifier to apply to the `AnyOfConstraint`, but it is being applied to the result of `IsAll`, which is a base level `Constraint` that doesn't support that modifier.

Barring changes to NUnit, you need a workaround. The simplest would appear to be

```
Assert.That(new string[] { "red", "red", "red", "green" }, 
  new AllItemsConstraint(
    Is.AnyOf(new string[] { "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN" }).IgnoreCase));
```

I haven't tried this, so check my syntax, spelling, etc.